# Is it possible to Style without any CSS ?(with just using photoshop like apps)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, photoshop, styling

I am a rookie web developer. I am trying to learn Rails. I was just wondering can I style my rails app without any CSS?

Or at least using Photoshop like apps for major part of design.

I don't want to lose time learning CSS. However I do want to learn Photoshop.

Can I style all my pages with Photoshop?

By styling, I mean:

- Where every element is gonna be?
- How buttons will look?
- Adding background images and colors?
- Changing text styles? etc. etc.

And if it is possible, can you guys suggest me a tutorial on how to do it?

Thank You Already.

Comment: Learning CSS will never be a loss of time... the questions you are asking have the answer : CSS

Comment: I know css is a good thing to learnd but i wonder, is it can be done without it?

Comment: You have to use CSS -- i do think there is no other way to style a web page...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use css :

from https://www.quora.com/Can-I-design-websites-without-using-CSS

> Yes. Use illustrator, photoshop, whatever to make your design. It
>   won't be a website, but it will be a website design that you designed.
>
> To make the website design into a website, you will need CSS unless it
>   is just plain text which nobody will like!

here is a website witout css : http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/

Comment: so ppl use photoshop like a tutorial ?to see the end product or to decide what to build ?

Comment: you can create a design with PS like, but to create a web page, you use css to give your design's elements their position for example

Comment: thank you.1 more question.lets say i have build this app and everything is cool.but i want to change the place of a button and dont know the css way of it.Can photoshop or any program can help me with that?

Comment: internet is full of tutorials html-css ! just dig more, and maybe set your topic answered

Comment: thanks. i think i will start learning css :). gotta learn it to achieve it i guess. or some vise words like that :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a decent website using only a photo editing tool. The problem is the difference in mediums - A webpage's look changes depending on the screen space available. For example, text may use two lines instead of one if there isn't enough space. Imagine constantly changing margins, paper size and/or orientation in Word. An image doesn't change like that.

I've seen Photoshop plugins that claim to generate HTML and CSS for you but it is all static/absolutely positioned. This is not considered a good practice for a modern website.

I would recommend that you either find another tool, or you learn the front end languages (HTML, CSS, JS)

Comment: so is photoshop just ike guide for css? Like, should i use photoshop  before starting desing, use photoshop to decide what css code will be required?

Comment: well i know somethings about web pages, i am just a little lazy and searching for an easy way

Comment: @HarunTuncay - You could use Photoshop to create a mockup, yes. However, it only serves as a guide for a **single possible size**. Many web designers use CSS media queries/breakpoints to limit the number of mockups needed to accurately represent the design. (Bootstrap takes this approach) This usually means that you have 4 or 5 different designs. You also need to know that the smallest is the default (mobile-first design) and everything else just re-arranges or adds to that design to better fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to use css to style webpages, but if you have Adobe Dreamweaver then it makes the whole designing a lot easier it's a partially WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor. Alternatively you could use a framework like bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com) or w3.css (http://w3schools.com/w3css). In terms of tutorials (http://w3schools.com/css) is quite good I think that alternatively you could use (http://codeacadamy.com) to learn.
Hope this helps...